# Learning ASP.NET Webforms with an MVC and Win Forms Background

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Ok this is going to be pretty odd but my last project was all ASP.NET MVC 3, WCF/REST/SOAP and Win Forms and WPF.

I know HTTP is stateless and I'm starting to get weirded out by the VooDoo that Web Forms is doing behind the scenes regarding web controls. I'm literally struggling wrapping my mind around DataBinding. Apparently, it's very different from the Win Forms DataBinding technique.

Are there any good patterns and examples that explain what is actually going on regarding DataBinding and Web Controls? I seem to keep treating it like it is constantly bound to some data source as I were programming for Win Forms.

Comment: [http://www.asp.net/](http://www.asp.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should learn about is the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). Once you've wrapped your head around that, you'll start to understand the mechanics of web forms. It might seem like magic because it's baked into the architecture, but it's really pretty simple once you understand it.

- [A low-level look at the ASP.NET architecture](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp)
- [ASP.NET data binding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)

There are a lot of differences between data binding in ASP.NET and WinForms, but the basic concepts still apply. The easiest way to understand data binding is to look at the source for a databound server control.

Here's what's going on behind the scenes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Binds the data source to the control.
/// </summary>
public override void DataBind()
{
    this.PerformSelect();
}

/// <summary>
/// Retrieves data from the associated data source.
/// </summary>
protected override void PerformSelect()
{  
    //if the control is bound from a datasource control then
    //fire the ondatabinding event
    if (!this.IsBoundUsingDataSourceID)
        this.OnDataBinding(EventArgs.Empty);

    //retrive the data source view object and bind the data to the control
    this.GetData().Select(CreateDataSourceSelectArguments(), PerformDataBinding);

    //mark that the control has been bound to the source
    this.RequiresDataBinding = false;
    this.MarkAsDataBound();

    //fire the on data bound event so it can be 
    //handled from the parent object
    this.OnDataBound(EventArgs.Empty);
}

/// <summary>
/// Binds data from the data source to the control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="retrievedData"></param>
protected override void PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable retrievedData)
{
    //call the base method
    base.PerformDataBinding(retrievedData);

    //clear all controls and viewstate data and reset
    //the viewstate tracking mechanism
    this.Controls.Clear();
    this.ClearChildViewState();
    this.TrackViewState();

    //generate all child controls within the hierarchy
    this.CreateControlHierarchy(true, retrievedData);

    //mark child controls created as true
    this.ChildControlsCreated = true;            
}
```

With all the heavy lifting being taken care of by the control, binding the data on the front end is incredibly easy; just set the `DataSource` and call the `DataBind()` method from the example above:

```
//assign the datasource to the control
GridView1.DataSource = new DataTable("DataSource"); 

//bind the datasource to the control
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I think this is the way I should go. I'm very confused by Web Forms' pagan ways coming from client-side and mvc-side programming. I wonder if there is a good site with good patterns and practices to help me understand it even further.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211027112438/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/default.aspx).  From memory the articles there are pretty comprehensive.